# Yorkshire Terrier, Long snout versus short snout?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

My question is pertaining to the Yorkshire Terrier (Yorkie). I am specifically referring to Champion line show breed. Apparently, Yorkies have two different types of snout. Some of them have Short Snout (which is Babyface), while others have Long Snout.

Via phone I have spoken with a breeder, who said that some breeders say the "Short Snout" has health problems. She also said that other breeders argue this point, and say they do not. Specifically that the ones with the smaller snouts have bite issues, and chewing, and so forth.

A good reference to a similar debate can be found here: http://www.yorkietalk.com/forums/general-yorkshire-terrier-discussion/105744-snouts.html

Besides conversations like this, actually resource material is hard to find. There is very little information about this online.

Hence my question, are there any health (or bite) issues related to a Short Snout, as opposed to a Long Snout?

Are there any other Pro's/Con's to one, as opposed to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is all I know from experience with dogs
Short snouts generally have respiratory and bite problems like how pugs do and long snouts generally don't have these. 
In my opinion long snouts are better for the animals health and wellbeing as they don't get as high a chance of respiratory problems and I have known about dogs that have had "braces" to sort out their bite problems